# Get innerHTML after the page loads completely

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting a make random quote machine with a tweet button to tweet the quote.
The random quote is coming up just fine. 
The code..

```
var forismaticAPI = 'http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=?';
$(document).ready(function() {
    var template = function(data) {
        $('#quotearea').empty();
        $('#quotearea').append('<blockquote id="quote">' + data.quoteText + '</blockquote>' + '<p id="author"> —  ' + data.quoteAuthor + '</p>');
        $('#quotearea').show();
    };

    var dataAppend = function() {
        $.getJSON(forismaticAPI, template);
    };
}
```

My next task is to get the quote content to be tweeted. So once the window loads completely i want to get the innerHTML of `#quote` which contains the quote. So i write a window.onload function like this..

```
window.onload = function(){
    var quote = document.getElementById('quote');
    console.log(quote.innerHTML);

}
```

But I'm getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null(…)`.. Since there is small delay in loading the quote, the window load function returns a null. How to get the innerHTML of a div only when the content is loaded and ready?

Comment: Could you instead put the innerHTML code inside of a success function inside the $.getJSON?

Comment: @BlueBoy
Like this?
`var loadfn = function(){
        var quote = document.getElementById('quote');
        console.log(quote.innerHTML);
    };

    var dataAppend = function() {
        $.getJSON(forismaticAPI, template, loadfn);
    };`
It is not working..no error..no console log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `#quote` element is created after the `window.onload` event, because it's only created on the return of your ajax call. Move the code from `onload` to `success` of the ajax call, as [BlueBoy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4678563/blue-boy) suggested in comments. In your case, the success function is the one you named `template`.

You can access your element immediately after creating it:

```
var template = function(data) {
    $('#quotearea').empty();
    $('#quotearea').append('<blockquote id="quote">' + data.quoteText 
    + '</blockquote>' + '<p id="author"> —  ' + data.quoteAuthor + '</p>');
    $('#quotearea').show();

    console.log(document.getElementById('quote'));
};
```

You can't call the `innerHTML` method on DOM elements that do not exist yet. So the first moment you can run your function is after the `append()` call, which is creating a DOM element with and `id` of `quote`.

Answer (score 0):

Without testing it, my guess is that onload is firing before the document ready.  So you may want to 1) set a flag when the content has been written, Then 2) check in the second function, if null schedule it to run again in 100 ms using setTimeout().

Answer (score 0):

use the **html** function?

```
var code = $('#quotearea').html();
```